# Windows/sublime text 'corrupting' files

Tags: windows, sublimetext2, windows-7-x64, text-editor

I am having a problem with text files on my work computer. They are regularly being corrupted and I can't tell if it is an OS problem (Windows 7) or problem with my text editor (Sublime Text 2), or both. Here's what's happening:

I am working on a coding project. I'll write some code, test it out, then save it. It may look something like this (I'm writing in Ruby):

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
  end
end
```

Then later, maybe the same day or the following day, I will attempt to run my code and will get a syntax error or invalid character error or unterminated string error, etc. I trace the error and find that one of my files will look like this:

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
  §`½š—ÍÚ
```

So I'll fix it and close the code blocks, and then run again. Often, I will get a second or third similar error and will have to trace out all of the files where this happens and fix the code.

The 'corruption' always occurs at the end of the file, so usually it is destroying some `end` statement for a class/module definition, but it also occurs at the end of scripts in the middle of `print` or `puts` statements, etc., wreaking a more general brand of havoc. (That is to say, it doesn't seem to only be happening to the keyword `end`.) The invalid characters that appear are not always the same characters, and so far I have not noticed any repeats.  The problem is destroying about 5-10 characters at the end of the file, including new lines (like my example above).

Also, it doesn't seem to be occurring in specific files. But I'm not sure if it is limited to the files in the folder(s) I have open in Sublime text or if it is happening to any files that I open for editing with Sublime text. 99% of the time I'm working in one directory which I have open in Sublime text for my project. I don't know if the problem would occur with another text editor (i.e. Notepad) because I haven't taken significant time to test it out (i.e. coding for a couple of days strictly in Notepad).

The problem occurs in files that are currently (at runtime) open in Sublime Text and have remained open since I last worked on them and saved, and also occurs in files that have been closed since their last use.

This is very frustrating as I feel like I can't trust that my work will be ready to go when I need it, and I have to spend extra time a couple of times a day fixing the files. I have searched for a solution and so far haven't hit on anything that seems to solve or even describe my problem - though I may not be using the best keywords.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you tell me what the test might identify as related to my problem? Do you have a recommendation for where to get the test from - http://www.memtest86.com/ or http://www.memtest.org/ or another? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, use the .org site. It's a utility that tests your machine's RAM. If random files are getting corrupted using an editor that millions of people user, the firsts thing to suspect the machine's RAM. Also check your hard disk.